# How to determine how many strings in a list using while loop in python?

Tags: python, list, loops, while-loop

I wrote this code below and I have a problem with the while loop, it runs through the list but when it finds a data type other than the strings it breaks and prints, I need it to go through all the elements of the list.

```
counter = 0
index = 0
a = ['some', 'apple', 'banana', lambda a: a, 
     'pear', None, 'cherry', """Hello world!""",
     '''The Who''', ("a", 5), [("a", "5"), ("b", 3)]]
while type(a[index]) == str:
    counter += 1
    index += 1
print("There are {} strings in the list".format(counter))
```

Comment: The first time you encounter a non-string in your list, is `type(a[index]) == str`? Therefore, will the loop continue? Could there be more strings in the list after that non-string? Therefore, *should* the loop continue?

Comment: " I need it to go through all the elements of the list." Then, what is the rule that tells you the maximum value of `index` to use?

Comment: I would suggest using a for-loop to iterate through all the elements.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this while loop this will solve your issue

```
while index < len(a):
    if type(a[index])==str:
        counter += 1
    index += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition you have set for the while loop is actually the thing you are looking to count, so it breaks as soon as it finds the first one. There’s another approach that may suit this better. Whenever you have an object that can be iterated over the easiest thing to use is a for loop. In this case it will go through each item in the list and you can then use that item in the loop.

So you can adjust the code to go through the whole list and count it as follows:

```
for i in a:
    if type(i) == str:
        counter += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through all the elements and "check" if they match your condition

```
counter = 0
a = ['some', 'apple', 'banana', lambda a: a, 
     'pear', None, 'cherry', """Hello world!""",
     '''The Who''', ("a", 5), [("a", "5"), ("b", 3)]]
for elem in a:
    if type(a) is str:
        counter += 1
print("There are {} strings in the list".format(counter))
```

A couple of things changed.

1. `for` loop is used instead of `while`. You need to loop over everything so for is a better choice here. You could still do similar thing using `while`, just not as clean.
2. `is` is used instead of `==`. For type exact match, `is` is faster and almost always better than `==`

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
len([elem for elem in a if isinstance(elem, str)])
```

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions here only evaluate the first level of strings in the object `a`.  This returns only 7 strings but in the example object there a total of 11 strings.

Below is an example method that recursively examines the object finding all strings, even if they are inside of another iterable.

Consider this method:

```
def is_string(input: any) ->  int:
    count = 0
    if isinstance(input, str):
        count += 1
    if isinstance(input, (list, tuple)):
        for e in input:
            count += is_string(e)
    if isinstance(input, dict):
        for k in input.keys():
            count += is_string(k)
        for v in input.values():
            count += is_string(v)
    return count


>>> is_string(a)
11
```

`is_string` accepts a parameter and determines if if its a string.  If so, it counts up and returns.  If however the input is an interable, it calls itself and passes in the interable.  You might notice that we're checking if they keys and values of dictionaries are strings here as well.

Answer (score -1):

**a more eficient way would be to use a dictionary or a json file.**

you need to chech first if the element of the list is another list, or a touple and loop over it, then check again if it is a list or a touple and loop over it again, and to get the value of that, loop again. 4 nested loops would be needed. A dictionary would be easier to handle. plus you have an array of mixed types, as you may know, the print statement just prints strings, so you should convert to string before print or the program fails.